# Problem with wordpress theme, the demo installation

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes, custom-wordpress-pages

[i'm getting this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5u2uw.jpg)

The execution failed. Please check error.log
anybody know what should i do ?
Put in consideration i'm not a programmer, so please if there is any easy way to solve the problem, i will appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

The best and Honest solution is to contact the theme developer.

They would be the perfect solution to your response.

Kind regards